# How to minify ES6 code using Webpack?

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, minify

I'm using webpack and want to deploy my site. If I minify and bundle my JavaScript code, I've got this error:

> **Parse error:** Unexpected token: name (`Button`)

Here is my not bundled code:

```
'use strict';

export class Button { // <-- Error happens on this line
    constructor(translate, rotate, text, textscale = 1) {
        this.position = translate;
        this.rotation = rotate;
        this.text = text;
        this.textscale = textscale;
    }
}
```

Note in bundled code the keyword `export` is removed. In development, there are no errors thrown. Here you could find my configuration file of WebPack:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

var PROD = true;

module.exports = {
    entry: "./js/entry.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: PROD ? 'bundle.min.js' : 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: PROD ? [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: { 
                warnings: false 
            },
            output: {
                comments: false,
            },
        })
    ] : []
};
```

If I change `PROD` to false, I've no error, if true I've got error from above. My question is can I enable ES6 in Webpack?

Comment: I assume you don't want to transpile your code with Babel?

Comment: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/babili-webpack-plugin and https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-es come to mind (but I don't know how to integrate the latter with webpack).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer to this, but now you can include the beta version of [uglifyjs-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin) as a webpack plugin and it'll use [uglify-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-es) which can minify ES6 code.

```
npm install uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
```

and then in your webpack.config.js:

```
const Uglify = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: ...,
    output: ...,
    plugins: [
        new Uglify()
    ]
};
```

Comment: Finally a great solution to minify using webpack! Thanks

Comment: After hours of digging, this was the only thing that solved my issue.

Comment: With these steps, one will get `Error: Cannot find module 'uglify-js'` since the dependency is not installed by default. How can I install `uglify-es` (preferably as a local dependency) and have the plugin use it?

Comment: I worked around this with `npm i --save-dev https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2.git#harmony-v2.8.22`.

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone else in a similar situation to @kleinfreund . If your minification target is ES5 - you still need to `npm i uglify-js --save-dev` as uglify-webpack-plugin has a dependency on it. If you're minification target is ES6 - you need to install the same as @kleinfreund above. This is covered in the docs under 'Install': https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/tree/v0.4.6

Comment: Took me ages to find this solution, if it wasn't for your post I would have still been pulling my hair out trying to get UglifyJs and Babel to play nice.

Comment: Hi.I've used your code but after code uglify got this error:ERROR TypeError: n._moduleDoBootstrap is not a function
  here is my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47162403/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin-error-typeerror-n-moduledobootstrap-is-not-a-function thanks

Comment: I followed your answer. It didn't work for me. Still methods and properties are not minified

Answer (score 45):

Just came to know that `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` also doesn't minify ES6 code anymore. They started doing so in some versions, but then `uglify-es` they used is no more maintained so they fell back to `uglify-js` which doesn't support ES6 minification. Full Details [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/releases)

If you want to minify `ES6` code, please take a look at [terser-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin)

> terser is a fork of uglify-es that retains API and CLI compatibility with uglify-es and uglify-js@3.

Install the plugin with NPM via:

```
npm install terser-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

or with yarn:

```
yarn add -D terser-webpack-plugin
```

Then, add the plugin in the in the `optimization` section of your webpack config:

```
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  //...
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()]
  }
};
```

Comment: This also works great with [babel ESM plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-esm-plugin), so you can ship ES6 code to browsers that support it :)

Answer (score 4):

Having this default webpack config:

```
> npm list -g  uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
+-- 
| `-- webpack@3.10.0
|   `-- uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6
`-- webpack@3.10.0
  `-- uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6
```

the following worked for me with an *esnext* target:

```
npm i -D uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
```

yielding the now local *uglifyjs-webpack-plugin*:

```
 > npm list  uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
 `-- uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@1.2.2
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')
...
plugins: [
    //new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin() @0.4.6 doesn't work
    new UglifyJSPlugin() // @1.2.2  works with esnext
]
```

See the related maintainer's posts:

- [Is ES6+ supported or not?](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/issues/237#issuecomment-366827877)
- [Rest parameters not recognized](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/issues/235#issuecomment-366758770)

Comment: how can i use optimiser with this set up?

Comment: @shorif2000  you should be able to pass optimization options via the constructor. Have a look at the [tests](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/blob/master/test/minify-option.test.js) in the Github repo

Answer (score 1):

Using the uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@1.2.2 solves my problem.

Also, in my webpack.config.js

```
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
            presets: [require.resolve('babel-preset-env')]
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's because `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` now uses `terser` under the hood, which is a maintained fork of the abandoned `uglify-es`.  If you need to manually configure `terser`, use the `terser-webpack-plugin` instead.