# Can I replace one package with another in my config file?

Tags: javascript, webpack, uglifyjs

I have this in my Webpack config:

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  compress: {
    screw_ie8: true, // React doesn't support IE8
    warnings: false
  },
  mangle: {
    screw_ie8: true
  },
  output: {
    comments: false,
    screw_ie8: true
  }
}),
```

Works fine until it stumbles upon an ES6 module and then it breaks because UglifyJS cannot handle ES6.

I've found an alternative, such as this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js-es6 but I don't know if I can replace the uglifyer from my config with something else. I'm quite new to messing with Webpack config.

Can this be done or should I do something else (maybe omit the module from uglifying)?

Comment: There is a package is called `uglify-es` although to be fair it's not too great (yet) when I tested it, it will get better.

Other than a library recommendation -
If you actually need ES5 output (to support old browsers) you'd use a transpiler (like babel or TypeScript) to convert your code to ES5 and then use uglify on _that_. That's in practice what people do and the common thing.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - I don't want to transpile to ES5 because transpiled to ES6 gives a smaller output + transpiling to ES6 is faster. I only have the issue with this one package. My question was - how to replace the current uglifyer inside webpack.config. I don't know how to do it, syntactically.

Comment: check out uglifyes

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer here: [How to minify ES6 code using Webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44287584/how-to-minify-es6-code-using-webpack)

In short, from the answer above:

```
npm install uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
```

or, in my case:

```
yarn add uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
```

and then inside my webpack.config.js:

```
const Uglify = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: ...,
  output: ...,
  plugins: [
    new Uglify()
  ]
};
```